# Use socket.io on apache

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I need deploy some apps which use socket.io, and I haven't did it because I have problems with paths.
My client side code is like

```
var io = io.connect("http:myweb.com");
```

The nodejs configuration for server is like

```
var app = require("express");
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require(server);
```

And on the server (owner is a client) and configuration for app and socket.io

```
<location /socket.io >
    ProxyPass http:localhost:3001
</location>

<location /chat >
    ProxyPass http:localhost:3001
</location>
```

I have some questions,

How can I allow to server answer to websockets?

How can I allow to server answer (to websockets) to different apps?